# Echo whole numbers (from array) from calculation from item price

Tags: php

I have a tricky question and would appreciate some suggestions.

A customer sets a price, then that price determines the number of customers that can purchase the item.

I think im looking to have an item price set from a form, then carry out a calculation in a loop, hold this in an array then echo out only whole numbers from the array to an options box which is populated by ajax onlclick.

At least I think thats how to do it.

E.G

itemPrice=50, therefore only the following no of customers can purchase the item.
50,25,10,5,2 or 1 as these are the only whole numbers from the calculation (this should be offered as a combo box or slider).

```
$itemprice = 50
for ($i=1, $i < $itemprice, ++$i) {
$array .= $i
}

for each {
is_int($array){
$NoOfCustomersList .= <option value="$NoOfCustomers">$NoOfCustomers</option> 
//(or jQuery slider)
}
}
```

DISCLAIMER

At least this is how it would look in my mind, I am new to php so the above may be jibberish

Comment: What calculation? Why `50, 25, 10, 5 or 1`?

Comment: All numbers that divide into 50 with no float.

Comment: Item price of 20 means the options that return would be 20,10,5,4,2 or 1 as these return whole numbers

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want only the numbers that divide 50, you can do this

```
$itemPrice = 50;
$array = array();

for ( $i = 1; $i <= $itemPrice; $i++ ){
    if ( $itemPrice % $i == 0 ){ $array[] = $i; }
}


foreach( $array as $item ){
    echo '<option value="', $item ,'"/>', $item ,'</option>';
}
```

Comment: Only the numbers up to 50 that divide into whole numbers. (no decimal)